# Led matrix display atmega32

Tags: led, resistance, microchip, led-matrix

I need help with an LED matrix I am building for my son, running from an atmega 32 and a BC818 transistor. I have the schematic from 
http://dhassel.de/projects/cool/led-matrix-display/
In the schematic there is no resistor value from BC818 pin to LED anode. I'm afraid that I will burn the atmel 32
http://dhassel.de/images/projects/2012-11-15-led-matrix-display/led-matrix-display8.png

Answer (score 2):

Normally a LED current of about 10mA is enough to turn a LED on quite brightly, but in a circuit where the LED's are multiplexed (they are not all on at the same time) you will need more current. Exactly how much more is sometimes difficult to judge without trying it. If we go for 20mA then the resistors will need to be 150 Ohms. Try that.

Answer (score 1):

The BC818 drive the columns directly in this multiplexer, the current limiting resistors R21-R40 are in the row drive. Each LED has a resistor in circuit when on. You include a resistor in the row drive, or the column drive, but not both.

The transistor without the resistor drives a whole line, that with the resistor selects which LEDs in the line are on. If you do it the other way, different numbers of LEDs on in the line will result in different brightnesses, as different currents flow through the resistor.